# Could not load file or assembly 'xxxLib' or one of its dependencies. BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net, badimageformatexception, assemblybinding

From what I've read in different posts, this is an error related to 32-bit and 64-bit applications. However, all of my projects are being built in x64.

### [image]

`xxxLib`, is an old library that is being used by the three projects that was recently updated to 64-bit. It was working fine. Until I added it to the `WebSite` project.

This is the current Assembly Load Trace:

> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>
> LOG: Using application configuration file:
>
> C:\Users\LuisLavieri\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Website\WebSite\web.config
>
> LOG: Using host configuration file:
>
> C:\Users\LuisLavieri\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>
> file:///C:/Users/LuisLavieri/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/8500ede2/8446907/xxxLib.DLL.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>
> file:///C:/Users/LuisLavieri/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/8500ede2/8446907/xxxLib/xxxLib.DLL.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>
> file:///C:/Users/LuisLavieri/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/WebSite/WebSite/bin/xxxLib.DLL.
>
> ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

So, if I'm not wrong it seems that it is trying to use the machine configuration file for 32-bit applications, right?

It appears in this line:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.

If that is the issue, how can I point the solution to use the 64-bit one?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that someone will find this useful.

In Visual Studio go to:

`TOOLS -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Check/Uncheck whatever User the 64 bit version...`